# git apply patch doesn't work: no such file or directory

Tags: git

Our repository was moved from GitLab to GitHub. I need to migrate some changes from my old working repository to the new one. I have two separate clones.

I ran: `git format-patch a3f98d38410c48be73a5fb4a6fa086c29ed6a7c1 --stdout > dan-changes.patch`

to create the patch file, then moved it to the other clone.

Then:

```
C:\Users\dbak\Projects\Flamenco.Flamenco-Firmware (dev-anom-stiction-test -> origin)
λ git apply -v dan-changes.patch
dan-changes.patch:793910: trailing whitespace.
                        virtual void format_error_message()const = 0;
dan-changes.patch:793911: trailing whitespace.

dan-changes.patch:793926: trailing whitespace.

dan-changes.patch:793943: trailing whitespace.

dan-changes.patch:793955: trailing whitespace.

Checking patch unit-tests/FlaAlgoTests/CMakeLists.txt...
error: unit-tests/FlaAlgoTests/CMakeLists.txt: No such file or directory
Checking patch unit-tests/FlaAlgoTests/flamenco_algorithms_gyro_anom_tests.cpp...
error: unit-tests/FlaAlgoTests/flamenco_algorithms_gyro_anom_tests.cpp: No such file or directory
Checking patch unit-tests/FlaAlgoTests/flamenco_algorithms_gyro_stiction_tests.cpp...
error: unit-tests/FlaAlgoTests/flamenco_algorithms_gyro_stiction_tests.cpp: No such file or directory
Checking patch unit-tests/FlaAlgoTests/flamenco_algorithms_tests_helpers.cpp...
Checking patch unit-tests/FlaAlgoTests/RealFlamencoData.csv...
Checking patch unit-tests/CMakeLists.txt...
Checking patch unit-tests/FlaAlgoTests/CMakeLists.txt...
error: unit-tests/FlaAlgoTests/CMakeLists.txt: No such file or directory
Checking patch unit-tests/FlaAlgoTests/CMakeLists.txt.in...
error: unit-tests/FlaAlgoTests/CMakeLists.txt.in: No such file or directory
Checking patch unit-tests/FlaAlgoTests/DataGenerator.py...
Checking patch unit-tests/FlaAlgoTests/OutputToXML.py...
Checking patch unit-tests/FlaAlgoTests/catch_test_runner.cpp...
Checking patch unit-tests/FlaAlgoTests/flamenco_algorithms_accel_anom_tests.cpp...
error: unit-tests/FlaAlgoTests/flamenco_algorithms_accel_anom_tests.cpp: No such file or directory
Checking patch unit-tests/FlaAlgoTests/flamenco_algorithms_accel_stiction_tests.cpp...
error: unit-tests/FlaAlgoTests/flamenco_algorithms_accel_stiction_tests.cpp: No such file or directory
Checking patch unit-tests/FlaAlgoTests/flamenco_algorithms_gyro_anom_tests.cpp...
error: unit-tests/FlaAlgoTests/flamenco_algorithms_gyro_anom_tests.cpp: No such file or directory
Checking patch unit-tests/FlaAlgoTests/flamenco_algorithms_gyro_stiction_tests.cpp...
error: unit-tests/FlaAlgoTests/flamenco_algorithms_gyro_stiction_tests.cpp: No such file or directory
Checking patch unit-tests/FlaAlgoTests/flamenco_algorithms_public_tests.cpp...
error: unit-tests/FlaAlgoTests/flamenco_algorithms_public_tests.cpp: No such file or directory
Checking patch unit-tests/FlaAlgoTests/flamenco_algorithms_tests_helpers.cpp...
Checking patch unit-tests/FlaAlgoTests/flamenco_algorithms_tests_helpers.h...
Checking patch unit-tests/FlaAlgoTests/test_runner.cpp...
error: unit-tests/FlaAlgoTests/test_runner.cpp: No such file or directory
Checking patch unit-tests/lib/csv.h...
```

So, it appears that `git apply` does not like the fact that new files were created in this patch. These are all files created in or since `a3f98d38410c48be73a5fb4a6fa086c29ed6a7c1` in the original clone. Is there any way to override this behavior? Or do I need to add a stub file manually for each new file in the new clone?

Comment: Isn't it possible to have both repos set as two remotes of the same project? So that you can cherry-pick without having to use patch files.

Comment: They need to be separate projects. As I had previously stated, our project was moved from GitHub to GitLab. So, I have one repo which is sourced from the old GitLab project, and a new repo which is sourced from the new GitHub project. It is necessary that I move changes from the former to the latter, as explained in the question.

Comment: Is there a policy-related problem to have a single project with two remotes? Technically, you can still have a single local repo related to both of them and that's why I asked... and if you have the two remotes on a single local repo, you can _easily_ move stuff from one to the other. Working with patch files can become a problem, as you are seeing. Anyway... the tree that you created the patch from and the one you are trying to apply the patch on are _equivalent_?

Comment: Unlike cherry-picking, working with patches gives git a lot less context to guess where things were moved and you can easily get the patch to fail in cases where cherry-picking would succeed without a blink.